# player jump audio interfearing with player death audio

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So Im having this problem where when I jump and land on my spikes/enemy my player will play my death animation but it will cut out when its almost finished, this is caused by me telling it to play my jump animation when isGoruded is false and Im really not sure on how to fix it. I told my game to play the jump animation when its not on the ground ands that's why its interfering with it but I want my game to stop playing the jump animation when it collides with the spike while jumping. I have making my jump animation false when the death animation is true, I have also tried making the jump animation true in other places.

My code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
 
public class PM : MonoBehaviour 
{
 
 
 public float moveSpeed;
 public float jumpHeight;
 Rigidbody2D rb;
 BoxCollider2D boxColliderPlayer;
 int layerMaskGround;
 float heightTestPlayer;
 public Animator animator;
 public Joystick joystick;
 float horizontalMove = 0f;
 
 
 
    void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
 
    // Get the player's collider so we can calculate the height of the character.
    boxColliderPlayer = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    // We do the height test from the center of the player, so we should only check
    // halft the height of the player + some extra to ignore rounding off errors.
    heightTestPlayer = boxColliderPlayer.bounds.extents.y + 0.05f;
    // We are only interested to get colliders on the ground layer. If we would
    // like to jump ontop of enemies we should add their layer too (which then of
    // course can't be on the same layer as the player).
    layerMaskGround = LayerMask.GetMask("Ground");
 
    //audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}
 
    void Update()
    {
 
        /// Player movement and playing the animtion
         if (joystick.Horizontal >= .2f)
     {
         horizontalMove = moveSpeed;
     }else if (joystick.Horizontal <= -.2f)
     {
         horizontalMove = -moveSpeed;
 
     }else
     {
         horizontalMove = 0f;
     }
 
     rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalMove, rb.velocity.y);
     animator.SetFloat("Speed",Mathf.Abs(horizontalMove));
 
 
     // Your jump code:
     if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded() )
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
            FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("PlayerJump");
 
        }
 
     if (IsGrounded() == true)
     {
        animator.SetBool("isJump", false);
 
     }
 
###### SAying if it is not colliding with the grounnd to play my jump animtion
     if (IsGrounded()== false) 
     {
        animator.SetBool("isJump", true);
 
      }
 
 
 
 
    }
    // End of update
 
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Coins"))
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
 
        }
 
    }
 
#### The not touching the ground is interfering with this code.
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "EnemyCollide")
        {
            animator.SetBool("Death", true);
            moveSpeed = 0.0f;
            jumpHeight = 0.0f;
            FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("PlayerDeath");
 
            //audioSource.PlayOneShot(impact, 0.7F)
        }
 
 
 
    }
 
 
    /// <summary>
    /// Simple check to see if our character is no the ground. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns <c>true</c> if the character is grounded.</returns>
    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
    // Note that we only check for colliders on the Ground layer (we don't want to hit ourself). 
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(boxColliderPlayer.bounds.center, Vector2.down, heightTestPlayer, layerMaskGround);
    bool isGrounded = hit.collider != null;
    // It is soo easy to make misstakes so do a lot of Debug.DrawRay calls when working with colliders...
    Debug.DrawRay(boxColliderPlayer.bounds.center, Vector2.down * heightTestPlayer, isGrounded ? Color.green : Color.red, 0.5f);
    return isGrounded;
 }
}
```

Comment: Is `Time.timeScale` being set to 0 on player death? Is the animation being played in unscaled time?

Comment: Yeah, its being played on an unscaled time. Its just that when I jump and hit my spike, since I told my player to play my jump animation when its not touching the ground and since its still not touching the ground, my jump animation plays in the middle of my death animation.